# how can i share a link or image from my web application to whatsup friends

Tags: share, whatsapp, data-sharing, linkshare

How can I  share a picture along with its link to  whatsapp contacts form my web application.   Using my mobile  I am able to share link.. using

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

But it does not work in PC. Please help me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**You Don't**

You can hide the link on big screens.

WhatsApp is not generally installed in your PC, laptops and big devices so its good idea to hide the share link for them.

Comment: okay. Thank you very much. Is it possible to share  link on Hike messenger from mobile

Comment: Please ask a different question or first search for the answer first